# With jquery or javascript how to store a input field value in an array and again display it when the space key pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have written a code to display a to z in a text field when anyone type anything in that textbox 
but now in that code i need to display the a to z one by one when user press space bar key .and also change the previous letter color when space bar pressed
so can one help me to do that , here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    var x=0
    function type()
    {
        var a=newArray("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z")
       var i=document.getElementById("type").value
       var n=i.substring(0,i.length-1)
       document.getElementById("type").value=n.concat(a[x]);
       if(x>=0)x++
       if(x>=26)x=0 
     }
</script>    
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="type" id="type" size="100" onkeyup="type()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there you go !

```
var letter_array = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"];

var pointer = 0; // start the pointer at 0 which means that the first letter will show is the a
var shown_letters=''
$('#type').keydown(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 32) { 
         if(pointer+1 == 26){
         pointer = 0;
         }
         shown_letters += letter_array[pointer];
         $('#type').val( shown_letters);
         pointer = pointer+1
       return false; // return false to prevent space from being added
     }
});
```

and you cant style the last letter different than others in text input

http://jsfiddle.net/m4eJx/